# Direct 3D can not draw after screen saver

Tags: direct3d9

I'm drawing YUV image onto window on Windows.

Every time a screen saver launched or screen turned off, the window can not show anything again after I woke up the screen. I mean, the window shows nothing even through every Direct 3D APIs returns OK.

What should I do to make sure the window show image properly after such conditions.

PS. I'm drawing images once every 2 sec (30 FPS).

Comment: Which version interface of Direct3D are you using and which OS? Legacy Direct3D9 experiences a 'lost device' scenario when the screen saver is enabled, which requires resetting. All DXGI-based APIs (Direct3D9Ex, Direct3D10, Direct3D 11, Direct3D 12) do not have 'lost device'. They do have ``DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED`` and ``DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET`` error cases which are similar but happen much more rarely and require destroying and re-creating all Direct3D objects. You should check the HRESULT you are getting back from ``Present`` when the screen saver is active and afterwords.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Direct3D9 on WindowsXP and Windows 7

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Thank you so much. Now I know all I have to do is reset the Render.